# Make public an implementation in rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-tokio

and I need some help:

I'm working with grpc in rust, my directoris is organized like:

```
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── src/
│   └── main.rs
├── user/
    └── user.rs
```

and I added this in `Cargo.toml` :

```
[lib]
name = "user"
path = "user/user.rs"
```

The `UserStruct` is implemented in `user/user.rs`

```
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub struct UserStruct {}

#[tonic::async_trait]
impl UserSvc for UserStruct {
   ...{code}
}
```

When I tried to use UserStruct in `main.rs` and I got :

```
the trait bound `UserStruct: UserSvc` is not satisfied
label: required by a bound introduced by this call

UserSvc` is not implemented for `UserStruct`
```

Comment: Can you add some more detail, if possible a complete [mre] not just snippets, I can't reproduce your error and the implementation should be public by default.

Comment: I found the error, I was import generated proto twice, in src/main.rs and in user/user.rs